# Installing glassfish on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, java

I downloaded glassfish-3.1.2.2-unix.sh from [glassfish.java.net](http://glassfish.java.net). To install I did

```
chmod +x glassfish-3.1.2.2-unix.sh
```

then i tried to run it :

```
$ ./glassfish-3.1.2.2-unix.sh 
This program requires DISPLAY environment variable to be set.
Please re-run after assigning an appropriate value to DISPLAY.
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DISPLAY variable tells the X11 libraries where the X11 server is located.

Try

```
 export DISPLAY=:0
```

I do not believe the Unix installer supports installing OS X services, so unless you have very explicit needs at this time you can get along just with the zip-distribution of Glassfish.  Unzip it and run `asadmin start-domain`.

Comment: It worked both ways :) Thanks...however what is this command doing ? export DISPLAY=:0 ...i googled for it but still not very clear ...

Comment: It is a shell environment variable which is being set and made available to future programs.  The ":0" means the first screen+keyboard on the local computer.   OS X does not use X11 by default or this variable would have been set transparently.